# Object.assign({}, obj) in ReactJs to replace objects of json

Tags: json, reactjs

I have `JSON` called by `fetch` request that looks like this:

```
[{
    "nameSecond": "",
    "Id": "",
    "First": {
      "nameFirst": "",
      "Id": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "nameSecond": "",
    "Id": "",
    "First": {
      "nameFirst": "",
      "Id": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "nameSecond": "",
    "Id": "",
    "First": {
      "nameFirst": "",
      "Id": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "nameSecond": "",
    "Id": "",
    "First": {
      "nameFirst": "",
      "Id": ""
    }
  }
]
```

I want to replace an object of another `JSON` to every object of this `JSON`. 
The second `JSON` which is going to be added to first `JSON` looks like this:

```
[{
        "nameFirst": "",
        "id": ""
},
{
        "nameFirst": "",
        "id": ""
},
{
        "nameFirst": "",
        "id": ""
},
{
        "nameFirst": "",
        "id": ""
 }]
```

What I did is that when `ChangeObjectFirst` was run ,the object is clicked will be replace by the object `First`of first`JSON` and new data will be shown.

```
 <div onClick={((e) => this.ChangeObjectFirst(e, i))}>Change</div>
```

I used `Object.assign({}, itemToReplace)` to replace objects but 
The main problem is that it will be done just for the first time. For the second time or more clicked object will not be replaced by object `First` and there will be this `TypeError: el is undefined`

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        dataNew: [],
        library: null,
        libraryNew: null,
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'POST',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            const Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))

    fetch('/json2.bc', {
        method: 'POST',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            const Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                dataNew: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibraryNew()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
}

reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library);
    this.setState({ library })

}

reorganiseLibraryNew = () => {
    const { dataNew } = this.state;
    let libraryNew = dataNew
    libraryNew = _.chunk(libraryNew);
    this.setState({libraryNew})
}

renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return ''
    }
    return library.map((item, i) => (
        <div>
            {item.First.nameFirst}
            {item.nameSecond}
        </div>
    ))
}

renderLibraryNew = () => {
    const { libraryNew } = this.state;
    if (!libraryNew || (libraryNew && libraryNew.length === 0)) {
        return ''
    }
    return libraryNew.map((item, i) => (
        <div>
            {item.nameFirst}
            <div onClick={((e) => this.ChangeObjectFirst(e, i))}>Change</div>
        </div>
    ))
}

render() {
    const { library, libraryNew } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderLibrary()}
            {this.renderLibraryNew()}
        </div>
    )
}

ChangeObjectFirst = (e, i) => {
    const itemToReplace = this.state.libraryNew[i];
    let { data } = this.state;
     data = data.map(el => {
        el['First'] = Object.assign({}, itemToReplace);
    });
    this.setState({ data: data });
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that while updating, you haven't returned the new data from map. Also since you are using library variables for rendering, you need to call reorganiseLibrary after updating data. A better implementation without mutation would be as below

```
ChangeObjectFirst = (e, i) => {
    const itemToReplace = this.state.libraryNew[i];
    let { data } = this.state;
     data = data.map((el, idx) => {
         return Object.assign({}, el, { First: itemToReplace});
    });
    this.setState({ data: data }, ()=> {this.reorganiseLibrary()});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri but nothing has happened. even there is not any error.

Comment: A simpler way would be using object spread: `{ ...el, First: itemToReplace }`

Comment: And for the first time it is not be replaced too.

Comment: @Rajesh you mean something like this:`data = data.map((el, idx) => {
         return Object.assign({}, { ...el, First: itemToReplace });
    });`

Comment: @sahar object spread is a replacement for Object.assign. Its a suggestion not a solution

Comment: You don't need object.assign, if you use spread `data = data.map((el, idx) => { return { ...el, First: itemToReplace }; });`.

Comment: @sahar Updated my answer

Comment: I changed to this: `ChangeObjectFirst = (e, i) => {
        const itemToReplace = this.state.AllLibraryFlight[i];
        let { data } = this.state;
        data = data.map((el, idx) => { return { ...el, First: itemToReplace }; });
        this.setState({ data: data });
    }`